# WhatsApp shared image just black

Tags: android, whatsapp

```
if (Utils.isPackageInstalled(getContext(), "com.whatsapp")) {
    Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
    sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

    Bitmap bitmap = Utils.screenShotBitmap(getActivity());
    Utils.saveImage(getActivity(), bitmap, bet.getID() + ".jpeg");
    File file = new File(getActivity().getFilesDir(), bet.getID() + ".jpeg");

    if (file.exists()) {
        Log.i("share", "file exists");
        Log.i("share", Uri.fromFile(file).toString());
    }
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Share text");
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(file));
    sendIntent.setType("image/*");

    sendIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
    startActivity(sendIntent);
}

// ...
public static Bitmap screenShotBitmap(Activity activity) {
    return Falcon.takeScreenshotBitmap(activity);
}

public static void saveImage(Context context, Bitmap b, String name){
    FileOutputStream out;

    try {
        out = context.openFileOutput(name, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
        out.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**Log-Output:**

```
03-25 17:13:24.328 26417-26417/x.x.x I/share: file exists
03-25 17:13:24.328 26417-26417/x.x.x I/share: file:///data/data/x.x.x/files/4b00abc2-7aae-4234-945b-59905306ad4a.jpeg
```

**Result:**
[image]

`Bitmap bitmap = Utils.screenShotBitmap(getActivity());` seems to work fine and return a correct Bitmap, because I can share it without problems to facebook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> because I can share it without problems to facebook

Not with that code.

You are writing the file to internal storage. Neither Facebook nor WhatsApp has access to your portion of [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html). Plus, [using `file:` `Uri` values is being phased out](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/03/14/psa-file-scheme-ban-n-developer-preview.html).

The correct long-term answer is for you to [use a `ContentProvider` to publish the bitmap](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/03/16/how-publish-files-via-content-uri.html), such as using `FileProvider`. In the short term, you can probably get away with writing to [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html), such as `getExternalFilesDir()`.

Also note that `ACTION_SEND` recipients do not need to honor both `EXTRA_TEXT` and `EXTRA_STREAM`, but only one or the other.

Comment: @Chris: It should work to API Level 4 (a.k.a., Android 1.6).

Comment: I'll try at come back at you. Thanks

Comment: `FileProvider` was the way to go. Thanks.